# Can I use strum to convert a string to f64?

Tags: rust

I am refactoring a [small stack based language](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/206745/small-stack-based-language-in-rust) I wrote and decided I would have a parser phase separated from the execution phase and as a result I would parse strings to a `Token` enum. I tried using [`strum`](https://github.com/Peternator7/strum) to do this, here is the smallest example I could manage:

```
extern crate strum; // 0.11.0
#[macro_use]
extern crate strum_macros; // 0.11.0

#[derive(EnumString)]
enum Token {
    #[strum(default="true")]
    Number(f64)
}

fn main() {
}
```

Basically, what this should do is if nothing is matched, default to parsing a float. So, convert anything it is given to float in this case. Which gave:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f64: std::convert::From<&str>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
5 | #[derive(EnumString)]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&str>` is not implemented for `f64`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <f64 as std::convert::From<u32>>
            <f64 as std::convert::From<i32>>
            <f64 as std::convert::From<f32>>
            <f64 as std::convert::From<i8>>
          and 3 others
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<f64>` for `&str`
```

I also tried adding a `impl` for the conversion:

```
extern crate strum;
#[macro_use]
extern crate strum_macros;

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for f64 {
    #[inline]
    fn from(s: &'a str) -> Self {
        // See footnote [1] for why conversion is done this way.
        s.parse::<f64>().unwrap_or(0.0).to_owned();
    }
}

#[derive(EnumString)]
enum Token {
    #[strum(default="true")]
    Number(f64)
}

fn main() {
}
```

However, this gives:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
 --> src/main.rs:5:1
  |
5 | impl<'a> From<&'a str> for f64 {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ impl doesn't use types inside crate
  |
  = note: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Because I use `strum` I could not put this on Rust Playground, but the `Cargo.toml` is:

```
[package]
name = "strum_test"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
strum = "0.11.0"
strum_macros = "0.11.0"
```

And the file I edited was in `strum_test/src/main.rs`. Is there a way to handle this behavior in `strum`, or is there at least another graceful way of handling this conversion from `&str` to `enum Token`?

---

<sup>1 In the language by design is supposed to be hard to make an error. Does it make sense to convert, for instance, `"lol"` to `0`? Not really, but my language does it anyway. More information is given in the CodeReview link.</sup>

Comment: The usual solution to implement an external trait for an external type is to use a newtype, e.g. `struct Float(f64)`. You can then implement `From` for `Float`, and use `Float` in your enum.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks! That seemed to do the trick! If you want, you can post it as an answer and I'll accept. (I just posted all the code that I ended up writing for reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of Sven Marnach's comment I added a `struct Float(f64)`. Here is all the code for reference:

```
extern crate strum;
#[macro_use]
extern crate strum_macros;

struct Float(f64);

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Float {
    #[inline]
    fn from(s: &'a str) -> Self {
        Float(s.parse::<f64>().unwrap_or(0.0).to_owned())
    }
}

#[derive(EnumString)]
enum Token {
    #[strum(default="true")]
    Number(Float)
}

fn main() {
}
```